# API Server sends response, but client doesn’t receive

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I set up a simple API following a tutorial, however using both hoppscotch and REST client in VSCode, I can‘t get a response.
Here the route file:

```
const express ‌= require('express')
const router ‌= express.Router()

router.get('/', ‌(req, res) => ‌{
‌    console.log(res)
‌    res.send({title:"hello·‌world!"})
})

module.exports ‌= router
```

Here the server file:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = express()

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL)
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Database.'))

app.use(express.json())

const studentRouter = require('./routes/student')
app.use('/student', studentRouter)

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started'))
```

I know the server receives the simple GET request

```
GET http://localhost:3000/student
```

I send with the REST client in VSCode, because it prints the res:

```
<ref *2> ServerResponse {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  outputData: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  destroyed: false,
  _last: true,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: false,
  maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
  _defaultKeepAlive: true,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
  sendDate: true,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  _contentLength: 24,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  _closed: false,
  socket: <ref *1> Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      constructed: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: true,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      dataEmitted: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
      data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
      error: [Function: socketOnError],
      close: [Array],
      drain: [Function: bound socketOnDrain],
      resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
      pause: [Function: onSocketPause]
    },
    _eventsCount: 8,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: [Object],
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 1,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      requestTimeout: 300000,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      connectionsCheckingInterval: 30000,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      noDelay: true,
      keepAlive: false,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      maxRequestsPerSocket: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 12,
      [Symbol(http.server.connections)]: ConnectionsList {},
      [Symbol(http.server.connectionsCheckingInterval)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 198,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound checkConnections],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 30000,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1
      },
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    _server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      requestTimeout: 300000,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      connectionsCheckingInterval: 30000,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      noDelay: true,
      keepAlive: false,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      maxRequestsPerSocket: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 12,
      [Symbol(http.server.connections)]: ConnectionsList {},
      [Symbol(http.server.connectionsCheckingInterval)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 198,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound checkConnections],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 30000,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1
      },
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    parser: HTTPParser {
      '0': null,
      '1': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
      '2': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
      '3': [Function: parserOnBody],
      '4': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
      '5': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
      '6': [Function: bound onParserTimeout],
      _headers: [],
      _url: '',
      socket: [Circular *1],
      incoming: [IncomingMessage],
      outgoing: null,
      maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
      _consumed: true,
      onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
      [Symbol(resource_symbol)]: [HTTPServerAsyncResource]
    },
    on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    setEncoding: [Function: socketSetEncoding],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
    [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 31,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
      reading: true,
      onconnection: null,
      _consumed: true,
      [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
    },
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
    [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
    [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
  },
  _header: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n' +
    'X-Powered-By: Express\r\n' +
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n' +
    'Content-Length: 24\r\n' +
    'ETag: W/"18-Y8DhZWqTRwecOn62dQBJUQHM4rU"\r\n' +
    'Date: Mon, 22 Aug 2022 13:32:43 GMT\r\n' +
    'Connection: close\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
  _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
  req: IncomingMessage {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: null,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: false,
      constructed: true,
      sync: true,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: true,
      dataEmitted: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    socket: <ref *1> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      setEncoding: [Function: socketSetEncoding],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 31,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    httpVersionMajor: 1,
    httpVersionMinor: 1,
    httpVersion: '1.1',
    complete: false,
    rawHeaders: [
      'user-agent',
      'vscode-restclient',
      'accept-encoding',
      'gzip, deflate',
      'Host',
      'localhost:3000',
      'Connection',
      'close'
    ],
    rawTrailers: [],
    aborted: false,
    upgrade: false,
    url: '/',
    method: 'GET',
    statusCode: null,
    statusMessage: null,
    client: <ref *1> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      setEncoding: [Function: socketSetEncoding],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 31,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    _consuming: false,
    _dumped: false,
    next: [Function: next],
    baseUrl: '/student',
    originalUrl: '/student',
    _parsedUrl: Url {
      protocol: null,
      slashes: null,
      auth: null,
      host: null,
      port: null,
      hostname: null,
      hash: null,
      search: null,
      query: null,
      pathname: '/',
      path: '/',
      href: '/',
      _raw: '/'
    },
    params: {},
    query: {},
    res: [Circular *2],
    body: {},
    route: Route { path: '/', stack: [Array], methods: [Object] },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kHeaders)]: {
      'user-agent': 'vscode-restclient',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
      host: 'localhost:3000',
      connection: 'close'
    },
    [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 8,
    [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
    [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
  },
  _sent100: false,
  _expect_continue: false,
  locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
  statusMessage: 'OK',
  statusCode: 200,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
  [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
  [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
    'x-powered-by': [ 'X-Powered-By', 'Express' ],
    'content-type': [ 'Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ],
    'content-length': [ 'Content-Length', '24' ],
    etag: [ 'ETag', 'W/"18-Y8DhZWqTRwecOn62dQBJUQHM4rU"' ]
  },
  [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
}
```

But I can also not find “Hello world“ in there.

Any idea what is happening here?

Edit:

It turns out that for some reason both hoppscotch.io and the local REST client in VSCode where unable to receive the response. I tested it again with a different API client (Postman) and that worked.

Comment: try moving ```const studentRouter = require('./routes/student')``` to the fifth line of the server.js and see if that fixes the issue, also do you get any error logs?

Comment: In your REST client, how did you send the request, and what was the result?

Comment: @FarhadFaraji moving the line does not fix it. I also do not get any error logs

Comment: All those `·‌` characters should be spaces

Comment: You won't see the response in the server-side log for `console.log(res)`. You need to check the actual response received by the client